# filtering a DataTable using LINQ

Tags: .net, linq, lambda

Consider a `DataTable` which contains columns:

```
  RefID : string  
RefName : string 
RefDate : DateTime
```

The DataTable does not contains any primary key.

I have another `List<string>` named `ExcludeMe`.

I would like to filter my `DataTable` and exclude all of the rows where values in `RefId` Column around found in the `ExcludeMe` list.

How can I achieve this using LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like:

```
dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>.Where(s => !excludeMe.Contains(s["RefID"].ToString()));
```

Haven't tried to yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
DataRow[] filterred = RefDataTable.AsEnumerable()
.Where(row => !ExcludeMe.Contains(row["RefID"].ToString()))
.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it but someting like this should work.

```
var out = dataTable.Where(x => excludeMe.contains(x.RefId);
var filtered = dataTable.Except(out);
```